# How to convert string to float32 in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I am a new user of tensorflow. I have the following tensor A:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=string, numpy=
array([b'1,2.0,32.29,42.1,16.0,0.60,46.0,0.0,26.0,0.0,-1.31,-0.9'],
  dtype=object)>
```

I want to get the following two tensors:

Tensor B: Convert Tensor A to float tensor and get first element of Tensor A:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=float, numpy=
array([1],
  dtype=object)>
```

Tensor C: Convert Tensor A to float tensor and extract last 4 elements of Tensor B

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=float, numpy=
array([26.0,0.0,-1.31,-0.9],
  dtype=object)>
```

Could you please tell me how I can get Tensor B and Tensor C from Tensor A? Documentation is confusing.

Answer (score -1):

```
temp_list = [1,2.0,32.29,42.1,16.0,0.60,46.0,0.0,26.0,0.0,-1.31,-0.9]
temp_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(temp_list)
temp_tensor[0]
temp_tensor[-4:]
```

You should read https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor for further discuss.

update one:

I try

```
temp_str = "1,2.0,32.29,42.1,16.0,0.60,46.0,0.0,26.0,0.0,-1.31,-0.9"
temp_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(temp_str)
tf.cast(tf.strings.split(temp_tensor, sep=","),dtype=tf.float32)
```

It raises error :

```
UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported [Op:Cast]
```

It seems that tensorflow doesn't allow convert string to float .

I'm not sure this can satisfy your needs:

```
tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(tf.strings.split(temp_tensor, sep=",").numpy(),dtype="float32"))
```

Update two :

I find the best answer :

```
temp_str = "1,2.0,32.29,42.1,16.0,0.60,46.0,0.0,26.0,0.0,-1.31,-0.9"
temp_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(temp_str)
tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.split(temp_tensor, sep=","))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as OP seems to be asking how to convert the string tensor to a numeric type, which you skip over.

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is that I need to convert byte type tensor to numeric tensor. Your temp tensor is not byte type

Comment: Thanks @DachuanZhao. Your last line of code was helpful

Comment: @xdurch0 I have added it ~